# "st" global variable in SPM8

Tags: fmri, spm

I have some legacy preprocessing code that is designed to use SPM8. In the alignment function, it refers to a global variable `st`, which as far as I can tell is not described in the SPM8 manual. I'm updating the code to SPM12, which does not refer to `st`.

**What exactly does `st` do in SPM8? Is there an equivalent in SPM12?**

Answer (score 2):

it seems that it is a struct variable that is central to how images are visualized in spm. I found a description in the spm source code in [this github repository](https://github.com/canlab/spm8/blob/009e377eab146c66128c3c879dc6ce453cb7c54c/spm_orthviews.m#L158) (I linked to the exact line where it is described, 158). You can check if it's the same in your spm8 installation by looking at the code of the file "spm_orthviews.m" which should be in the spm8 folder but I'm pretty sure it is the original version. They also use it in [this how-to on wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPM/How-to#How_to_choose_the_colour_limits_in_a_rendering.3F) but I'm not entirely sure if it's exactly the same.

You can look at the same file in the spm12 folder (if it still exists) to find out if there is an equivalent.

**Comment:**

If you use this variable in your own script do your future self and others a favor and give it a meaningful name.